# Matrix Subtraction of Two Lists and Adding Absolute Value of Results to New List

Tags: python

So I'm trying to subtract the values of one list by another and then put the absolute values of those results in a new list. Essentially it will look like this:
[0,1]-[1,0]= abs([-1, 1]) = [1,1]

After that, I need the average of the final list:
mean([1,1])=1

So in all I'm:
1. Subtracting values of one list from another
2. Adding absolute values of subtraction results to new list and
3. Printing the average of the final list

```
lyst=[0,1]
pred=[1,0]
AE=[]
for x in pred:
    avgList = lyst - pred
    AE.append(avgList)
    avgAE=mean(AE)
print(avgAE)
```

Right now my results are an error stating: TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for -: 'list' and 'list'. This is happening because lyst - pred won't work currently.

Results need to be: 1, the average of the final list

Comment: You are performing vectorized operations on lists. That won't work. Either you convert to NumPy array OR you use a for loop to get individual element

Comment: Thanks! I'm in an intro course and we haven't covered NumPy yet. I ran the For loop option and that did exactly what I needed it to do. Thanks again for your help.

Comment: You are welcome. All the best. Glad to help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are many other direct approaches but here is a working version of your own code. The problem in your approach was that you were performing vectorized operation (diference) on lists. That is not possible with lists. Either you convert to NumPy array OR you use a for loop to get individual elements. Here you loop over the length of the lists and then take the difference **element-wise**. You then append the difference to a list and then outside the for loop, take the `sum` and divide by the number of elements to get the average.

```
lyst=[0,1]
pred=[1,0]
AE=[]
for i in range(len(pred)):
    AE.append(abs(lyst[i] - pred[i]))
avgAE=sum(AE)/len(AE)
print(avgAE)
# 1.0
```

**Vectorized approach (using NumPy)**

PLEASE NOTE: This is an overkill for your purpose but still I think you should know about this. `abs` is to get the absolute values.

```
import numpy as np

lyst=np.array([0,1])
pred=np.array([1,0])
AE= abs(lyst-pred) # Take the difference element wise in a vectorized fashion
avgAE=np.average(AE)
print(avgAE)
# 1.0
```

Answer (score 1):

Without using `numpy`, I would suggest a list comprehension with `zip`:

```
lyst=[0,1]
pred=[1,0]

AE = [abs(x-y) for x,y in zip(lyst,pred)]
avgAE= sum(AE)/len(AE)

>>> AE
[1, 1]
>>> avgAE
1.0
```

**Explanation**

What this does is zips your two list together:

```
>>> list(zip(lyst,pred))
[(0, 1), (1, 0)]
```

Then iterates through and gets the absolute value of the subtraction of each "group" (the `abs(x-y)` portion of the list comprehension).

Comment: `'sacul'[::-1]` = `'lucas'` ;)

Comment: I suppose it's time to come up with a more sophisticated encryption algorithm :-)